# How to join in direct discovery?

Tags: qlikview

I have a large query that can't go in memory. This query involves joining a few tables.. We are using a "DIRECT QUERY" to pull the data out of a database.

How would I write a query that has joins in the SQL with Qlikview direct discovery? Is it possible to do?

Comment: Might be easier if you create a view in the database that is joining the tables and use this view in the direct query select

Comment: So, is there no way to do it in Qlik? I am trying to set it up dynamically so that users can refresh based on parameters that they feed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This guide outlines how to join in direct discovery. You can do a where = join or use the JOIN keyword.

https://help.qlik.com/sense/1.1/en-US/online/Subsystems/Hub/Content/DirectDiscovery/MultiTableSupportDirectDiscovery.htm